# M1 mac mini: Python reports `mach-o, but wrong architecture`

Tags: mac-mini, python, apple-silicon

We've rented a M1 Mac Mini at a Cloud provider and installed `python3` via homebrew.

However, when installing packages, we see many errors reporting wrong architecture mismatches.

```
pip3 install <something>

/private/var/folders/s9/94x83w5x5gv1tkw6pgcvy55r0000gn/T/pip-install-6zb2vf39/rchitect_2226cf31d84b4fbeb14084a47e566d22/.eggs/cffi-1.14.5-py3.9-macosx-11.4-arm64.egg/_cffi_backend.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Other CLI libraries work just fine with their (native) brew installations. Rosetta is not even installed.

I am not heavily into Python and searching the web did not help, hence I suspect something non-standard might be going on here.

```
brew info python3
python@3.9: stable 3.9.5 (bottled)
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5 (3,108 files, 55.5MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-05-27 at 20:07:29
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/python@3.9.rb
License: Python-2.0

which python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
```

Does anyone have a clue what might be going on?

**Edit**: Here are the architectures of the files

```
file /opt/homebrew/bin/python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64

file /private/var/folders/s9/94x83w5x5gv1tkw6pgcvy55r0000gn/T/pip-install-nq_w_w15/rchitect_e1cd9cd747dc44e2a7f69885db619a02/.eggs/cffi-1.14.5-py3.9-macosx-11-arm64.egg/_cffi_backend.cpython-39-darwin.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

The downloaded egg of `cffi` is the wrong architecture. Why is this happening and who might be the bad player here?

Comment: You need to see what architecture all these files etc are the command that does that is file. the output ends with : Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64

Comment: Do you have an example of such a package so that others can try to reproduce? And please, as already mentioned, run `file /private/var/folders/s9/94x83w5x5gv1tkw6pgcvy55r0000gn/T/pip-install-6zb2vf39/rchitect_2226cf31d84b4fbeb14084a47e566d22/.eggs/cffi-1.14.5-py3.9-macosx-11.4-arm64.egg/_cffi_backend.cpython-39-darwin.so` and add the result to the question.

Comment: Thanks! Just added the outputs. The egg has the wrong arch - now the Q is: why is this the case? And can I somehow force/tell pip3 to use the arm64 builds?

Comment: What ios the exact pip command you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pypi does not provide an ARM package for this software for macOS.  Only X86_64.

How do I know?

I actually went and looked.

https://pypi.org/project/cffi/#files

PS: As of 2021-10-13 there appears to be an ARM build of `cffi` in PyPy.

Comment: Thanks. It is possible to tell `pip` to install the package from source (i.e. the tarball) or some completely different way I am overlooking? It should be possible to install/compile any python package on arm64 in general, shouldn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily.  There are instructions on the cffi homepage about building it from source.   That's not what pip is for.

Comment: Thanks. So AFAICS the authors need to build arm64 macOS wheels by themselves and upload them to pypi. Another alternative would probably be to build the wheels locally on the machine - I'll try this next.

Comment: Another alternative would be to follow the instructions on the cffi homepage, which give specifics for macOS.  But hey, pointing that out twice now.

Answer (score 1):

I had some similar issues with `regex` and `typed_ast`. I was running all my code from a Rosetta terminal and had installed Python from brew, via "arch -arm64 brew install".

My bodge solution was to uninstall the offending libraries and reinstall with:
`arch -arm64 pip install typed_ast --no-binary :all:`

In practice it's probably better to be more consistent with whether you're using Rosetta or not for everything, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem trying to install dask.
I solved it following these steps:

1/ Check which version of python are installed (I have : mac os python 2.x and 3.x, anaconda 3.8, brew 3.9):

```
python -m pipenv.help
```

Python installations found:

- `3.9.6`: `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`
- `3.9.6`: `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.9`
- `3.8.8`: `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3`
- `3.8.8`: `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3.8`
- `3.8.2`: `/usr/bin/python3`
- `2.7.16`: `/usr/bin/python2`
- `2.7.16`: `/usr/bin/python2.7`

2/ Use pipenv to create a 3.8 virtual environment:

```
pipenv install --python '/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3'
pipenv install 'dask[complete]'
```

Note: by default, pipenv was using the 3.9 brew version of python to create the virtual environment - which caused the problem.

3/ Activate the virtual environment and use it:

```
pipenv shell
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apple's `python3`, then it comes as a Universal Binary, so you can run it in Rosetta until the modules have caught up.